# Dumbledore's elder wand

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the movie Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince,

> after Dumbledore was killed, in the morning of the next day, Harry went to Dumbledore's office and found the Elder Wand there. Later the wand was inside the grave of Dumbledore.

When was the wand actually put into the grave? Did someone later reopen the grave?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably during the

> burial, which would have to have happened after that visit to the office

although it is not shown in the movie.

Comment: Is it written in the book like that? I haven't read the book

Comment: The ceremony is the last chapter in the book - after the visit to the office - and well after Fawkes has left, which is the last scene in the movie but happens before the visit to the Headmaster's office in the book.